# Sublime snippet for console.log in printf-style multiple variables using regex substitution

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I'm trying write a Sublime snippet that uses regex substitution to create something like this:

[image]

It should parse the text for `%s`'s and add corresponding comma separated placeholders after the text.

Here's what I could come up with but it doesn't work quite as expected:

```
console.log('$1',${1/%(\w)/$1,/g});
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with a [snippet](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html). Snippets run once, they don't constantly evaluate the text being entered in the way you want them to - one or more fields may have a regex attached to it, which will be applied as the field is filled out, but it can't parse for an arbitrary number of fields.

You could probably write an [`EventListener`](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime_plugin.EventListener) plugin in Python to do this, however.

Comment: Hmm I suspected so too. Thanks for confirming, and for the plugin idea, I'll look into it.